# How to get an html input value from an jQuery ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, jquery-ui

How can I get the specified input value from an ajax request callback data?

```
$('#action .add').click(function () {
                var form = getCreateUserForm();  // GET THE FORM TO CREATE USER               
                console.log(form);
                $('#user_dialog').html(form);
                $('#user_dialog').dialog({
                    modal: true,
                    width: 700,
                    height: 600,
                    resizable: false,
                    //draggable: false,
                    title: '<h3>' + ???? + '</h3>', // HERE! HOW TO GET THE INPUT VALUE
                    open: function (e, ui) {
```

In my view, I have this

```
 @Html.Hidden(@Localization.CreateUser, null, new { id = "title" })
```

The data is actually inside the `form` variable.

how could I get the localization name from the `form` variable?

or is there any way to handle such situation? am I on the right track?

**EDIT**

html:

```
  <div id="user_dialog" hidden></div>
```

Try to get the form:

```
  function getCreateUserForm() {
            if (formCreateUser == null) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("Create", "User")',
                    async: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        formCreateUser = data;
                    }
                });
            }
            return formCreateUser;
        }
```

The dialog has not been opened yet, I could not refer to it using $('#title')

**MY SOLUTION**

I found the HTML generated by `@Html.Hidden` is like

```
<input id="title" name="Create User" type="hidden" value="">
```

instead of using `$('#title').val()`, i change it to `$('#title').attr('name')`.

now it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
title: '<h3>' +$("#title").val()+ '</h3>'
```

Comment: according to the sample you have provided you have allready added the html. $('#user_dialog').html(form);

Comment: no that is not.. check the response of the request you are sending to fetch the html of the form. i think the problem lies there